# float divs next to each other indefinately

Tags: css

I have this problem:

```css
.container {
    height: 500px;
}

.tile {
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/dv4zqkw5/

What I need is to display each **tile** next to each other. The problem is that there could be 5 tiles or 20 (because they are dynamically loaded).
I am trying to get something similar to the way the windows 8 menu works, but I can not seem to get the scroll bar to appear and to horizontally scroll.

I tried:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

but this did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make the child divs display inline-block instead of floating them left, you can add a white-space:nowrap rule to the parent and get what you want:

```
.container {
    height: 500px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.tile {
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    display:inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dv4zqkw5/1/)**